# Vim: Select all without scrolling away

Tags: vim

is it possible in vim to select all lines in the current file, but leave the position where my cursor is unchanged?

Let's say I am currently at line 500 (of 3000) and want to quickly select everything (not yank), as my selection is simply set up to show whitespace characters. Can this be done without leaving my current line?

Comment: No, visual selection is defined by the motion of your cursor so visual mode *always* imply moving the cursor. Why do you want to select everything anyway? Selection is only a means to an end and Vim often has easier and faster means than selection.

Comment: If all you are trying to do is show whitespace characters then you might be better off just having a toggle for the `list` option.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve exactly what you like, you can press the following:

```
ggVG<Esc><Ctrl-O><Ctrl-O>
```

- `gg` moves to the beginning of the file
- `V` starts visual line mode
- `G` moves to the and of the file (now you have selected the whole
  file)
- `<Esc>` leaves visual mode
- `<Ctrl-O>` moves your cursor back to the prevois location (first to the beginning of the file, then the second time to your last position before pressing `gg`)

And if you like to select only the visible lines in you window (to not scroll away). You can use `HVL` instead of `ggVG` (`H` moves to the top of your window and `L` to the bottom).

You also could show whitespaces without using visual selection with something like this in your .vimrc:

```
set list listchars=tab:»·,trail:·,nbsp:·
```

This helps me to detect trailing whitespaces, and mixed (spaces/tabs) indentation.

Comment: The return to the cursor position only works, once I deselect the text again.
My current config looks like this:
`map <C-a> ggVG<C-o><C-o>`

Comment: Hmm, I think you got me wrong. I want to stay inside the visual mode, but not go to the end of the file when selecting all.

Comment: To reselect last selected in visual mode (i.e. whole buffer) use `gv`, the map would be: `nnoremap <C-a> <Esc>ggVG<Esc><C-o><C-o>gv`

Comment: Ctrl-A is usually a shortcut already in terminal, like Ctrl-Shift-C, therefore, if Vim-mapped to it, disable that shortcut in terminal Preferences/Settings.

Answer (score 0):

usually pressing

> ggVG

in normal mode will select all the lines, but it will leave your cursor at the last line of the file.
If you wants to highlights the whitespace characters then you can highlight this by using the below command in command mode (this white color chosen is for dark theme)

```
: hi ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=White guibg=White
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve you can use something like :

```
%cmd
```

To apply the command to the whole file.

For example, `%y` will yank the whole file, `%=`will format the whole file, without moving your cursor. It does not really work if you do something like `%d`...

It is not a real selection though but rather a way to apply a command on the whole file.

To go further you can use something like

```
%norm Atest
```

To add 'test' at the end of each line. (Actually this is a bad example, because this command will move to the last line...)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have the cursor inside a visual selection. This caused by that, vim defines visual selection through two marks. As soon as you move the cursor one of the marks gets updated. Basically this means one of the marks is always lays where the cursor is(at least when using "v" to select). You cannot have the border in the middle of the region that the border defines :)